# show H is a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a finite abelian group. Let $H=\langle a,b\rangle = \{a^{i}b^{j}\;\;\;i,j\in\mathbb{Z}\}$
Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$

My solution.

1) Need to show $H\neq\emptyset$

This is true as we can take $i=j=0$ then $a^{0}b^{0}=1\in H$

2) closure

let $a^{i}b^{j}\in H$ and let $a^{k}b^{r}\in H$ then $a^{i}b^{j}a^{k}b^{r}=a^{i+k}b^{j+r}\in H$

3) let $a^{i}b^{j}\in H$ then $a^{-i}b^{-j}\in H$ as we can take $i=j=-1\in\mathbb{Z}$

So $H$ is a subgroup of G

Is this correct?

Thank you

Comment: you might want to say $H$ contains identity when you type "Need to show $H\neq 0$"

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it!

Comment: your idea is correct but you might want to check the proof formation once again... what do you actually have in your mind when you say "3) let $a_ib_j∈H$ then $a^{−i}b^{−j}∈H$ as we can take $i=j=−1∈Z$"

Comment: @RobertLewis: Thank you

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I want to show that for every element in $H$ it's multiplicative inverse is also in $H$

Comment: yes but for that why do you want to consider $i=j=-1$..

Comment: @ Heidi:  I'm afraid I didn't read your post quite carefully enough; Praphulla Koushik's comments illuminate.  As does bateman's answer below.  Sorry if I in my haste caused any confusion; as Treebeard the Ent said in LOTR, "Let us not be hasty."  Also, see my answer, to appear momentarily.  Cheers.

Comment: @RobertLewis That is okay Robert:). No confusion has been caused.  I am happy I got most of the things right. Thanks again. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 3), if you take $i=j=-1$, you have $a^ib^j=a^{-1}b^{-1}$. Better say: since $i,j\in \mathbb{Z}$, then also $-i,-j$ are integers, thus $a^{-i}b^{-j}$ is in $H$ as well.

Comment: I would say this is better suited as a comment (Personal opinion)...

Comment: Thank you bateman. I like your formulation, much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty little factoid which you all may find intrigueing:  (2) is sufficient to establish that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$; this follows from the finiteness of $G$.  Indeed we have that if $S$ is a *finite, closed (under the group operation) subset* of *any* group $G$, then $S$ is a subgroup of $G$.  For if $s \in S$ we have $s^n$ in $S$ for all positive integers $n$, by closure.  Finiteness of $S$ implies the sequence $s^n$ must repeat itself; thus $s^i = s^j$ for some positive integers $i < j$, whence $1 = s^{j - i} \in S$.  Also, since $ss^{j - i -1} = s^{j - i} =1$, we have $s^{-1} = s^{j - i -1} \in S$.  Thus $S$ is a subgroup of $G$.  In the case at hand, $G$ finite implies $H$ finite and the desired result follows.  Essentially, $\text{(2)} \Rightarrow \text{(1) and (3)}$ in the case of $H$ finite.***QED***

***Nota Bene:***  This technique may be used to extend the result to finite but non-abelian $G$.***End of note.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***